# How to adjust mouse pointer speed in login screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, login-screen

I have a high-resolution laser mouse. To get a mouse pointer speed usable by mere mortals, I have to set the mouse pointer speed pretty low in the Mouse CP Applet. That's not a problem, of course.

The problem is that this setting, being for my account only, does not apply to the login screen. So every time I turn on the computer (or log out), I have to navigate ever so carefully to hit my login picture so I can enter the password and log in (and as of Windows 7, it seems I can no longer use the keyboard to select it either).

I assume that the settings that apply to the login screen are those associated with the All Users account template thingy (or maybe not?), but as I cannot log in to that "account", I cannot easily adjust the mouse settings. This might go for some other settings too, but can't actually think of any right now.

Anyway, does anyone know of a good trick? I'm prepared to hack the registry, if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Export your mouse settings from the Registry at

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse
```

Edit the .reg file and use Find and Replace to change `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\` to `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\`

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Control Panel\Mouse
```

Run the .reg file to import the new settings.

Comment: Thanks, I'd thought it might be something like this, but you've helped with the Registry locations.

Answer (score 2):

Not the solution for your mouse woes, but ...

> and as of Windows 7, it seems I can no
>   longer use the keyboard to select it
>   either

**TAB** and **Arrows up/down** to navigate and **Enter** to select works just fine in the welcome screen.